# Entity Framework Core inconsistent performance

Tags: sql-server, transactions, entity-framework-core, database-performance, ef-core-2.1

I have very inconsistent performance using EF Core for big transactions with create/update/delete.

1. API times vary 150-800 ms. https://www.screencast.com/t/KfwtT5yJv0
2. SQL times vary 15-300 ms. https://www.screencast.com/t/7YuVdWp9c6

What can be cause for this? Queries are doing exactly same thing.

Something like "delete existing copy, create new copy from original".

Comment: Can you check the generated query

Comment: It's only a bunch of INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements. I don't see anything special about it.